# Exchange 2007 Standby Continous Replication (SCR)

Tags: backup, exchange, exchange-2007, imaging

Ok I know that the OS and exchange versions have to be the same (Im not sure on the hardware) hence reason for this question to save quite a bit of time.
Is it possible, using something like GHOST or Acronis, to image and replicate the setup and transfer it onto a new server so that the implementation of SCR is quicker?
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother? Installing Exchange 2007 is fairly quick and easy, and the lion's share of the configuration information is stored in Active Directory anyway.

Perhaps I'm just old-fashioned, but I'm distrustful of disk-duplicated server computers, unless such disk duplication is part of a deployment / provisioning strategy and is based on disk-dupes of clean OS loads (decanting a WIM file that has had SYSPREP run on it, etc). Disk-duping machines with already-installed application software, like Exchange, gives me the willies.

Comment: Agreed, not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange has an unattended setup (look at setup.com /?) which you can use to automate the setup - really pretty easy. If you want the rest automated, the PowerShell scripts aren't that bad.